# Sparks+Php-activerecord - is it worth to use it?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I've recently 'discovered' Php-activerecord for use with CodeIgniter (using Sparks).
It is surely an easier way of building queries and getting data in and out of the database
than coding the models for yourself.

So my question is: is somebody using php-activerecord, instead of CodeIgniter's builtin activerecord, for a large project (ie. larger than the typical, tutorialish 'blog' example)?
What pitfals are there, when moving on from CodeIgniter models?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord seems to be a well known pattern. In your particular case you should bare in mind, that you no longer need the CodeIgniter AR classes and methods.

Extending the php-activerecord models gives you many standarized methods dealing with your data. That's a good portion of code you would have to type in for yourself over and over again in each project (and beacause of the common CRUD actions, the code would be almost the same).

Answer (score 2):

Great library!

I use it with my current CMS under development. 
Once you get your head around relationships its a breeze.  Activerecord\Model class is a joy to work with I find, however it would be nice to have a benchmarking wrapper.  Really though if you have set your database architecture up right by indexing your foreign keys it should help.

Some nice features

[callbacks](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Callbacks)

[eager-loading](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/news/5-did-you-know-php-ar-has-eager-loading)

Answer (score 0):

I have not personally used php-activerecord but it looks like a good ORM with good documentation. It looks like a nice time saver for larger projects, but for smaller ones i'd probably just stick with the standard activerecord class.